# Is there a simple way to manage files stored on a S3 bucket (via Mac Finder or FTP Client)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-management

I need to upload files (mainly pdf documents) into folders within an Aws S3 bucket.

Example :
PDF files containing keyword `accounting` in filename need to go to `accounting` folder
PDF files containing keyword `HR` in filename, need to go to `HR` Folder
PDF files containing keyword `ops` in filename, need to go to `operations` folder

and so on.

So far I've been using the AWS S3 interface using firefox (or any browser actually) but it is very tedious

Is it possible to connect/access the bucket as a remote directory and manage files (move, rename, drag and drop upload) via Mac Os Finder, or Windows explorer, an FTP Client or even via CLI (i'm familiar with bash basics) ?

Thanks

So far, i'm only able to access the bucket via the web browser, double click to go through directories until i reach the desired folder, upload the files that need to go there, go back up in the directory tree, access a different folder, upload files etc...

It works but I'm sure there is a more efficient way.

Comment: The [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is the standard CLI app to access AWS services, including S3.  Third party applications are available as well, such as [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/) that support S3.

Comment: Use the AWS SDK within a supported program language  to perform this use case.

Answer (score 2):

There are *many* apps that know how to communicate with Amazon S3.

For the Mac, some examples are [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/) and [Commander One](https://ftp-mac.com/amazon-mac.html). They allow drag-and-drop copying to/from S3.

You can also use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to copy files from the Terminal window.

You could also script your requirement to move files to different destinations based on filename:

```
aws s3 cp . s3://my-bucket/accounting/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*accounting*"
aws s3 cp . s3://my-bucket/HR/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*HR*"
aws s3 cp . s3://my-bucket/operations/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*ops*"
```

These commands will find any files in the current directory that include a particular word and then copy them to S3 into the correct directory.

See: [s3 — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

Comment: Cyberduck does the job ! Thanks for the CLI and the script idea.